# Почему на js в vs code не работает интерполяция выражений типа: ${var}?

Tags: интерполяция

this is my file .js:

```
    const name = 'Vlad'
    const age = 26
    const output = 'Hello my name is ${name} and my age is ${age} years'
    console.log(output)
```

the terminal in chrome:

```
Hello my name is ${name} and my age is ${age} years
```

How i can fix that?

Comment: что значит "не работает"?

Comment: типо в терминале хрома выражение отображаеться так же как в коде, а по идее такой способ можно использовать вместо конкатинации. Типо должно переменную отображать которая в скобках

Comment: Кавычки неправильные.

Comment: спасибо огромное))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для интерполяции используются обратные кавычки (где буква "ё" на клавиатуре)

```
` `
```

а не одинарные или двойные

Comment: Спасибо, очень помог)))

Comment: @Svyat_0x4b6 галочку слева от ответа тык!))